# Lambda operation on string to check digit

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I am learning c# and I came across Lambda expression. Can I convert following code block to lambda expression for any given string :

```
        foreach (var c in str)
            if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                return false;
```

Here I am trying to make sure string contains digits only . Sorry if it seems too noob but I am having difficult time wrapping lambda around my head.

A little code snippet will be very helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "convert to lambda expression". Something like `str.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9')`?

Comment: I mean I wanted to check for a given string if it contains digits only  then return true else return false.

Comment: Alternative to Kevin's solution that matches your current logic: `str.Any(c => c < '0' || c > '9');`

Comment: @KevinGosse note that an empty string will return `true` (as there are no characters that are not digits)

Comment: I'm not sure you know exactly what you want... The following is your code converted to a Lambda Expression: `str =>{foreach (var c in str){if (c < '0' || c > '9'){return false;}}return true;};` - I suspect that is not what you want but that *is* a lambda expression. Were you after a LINQ expression or something else like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine the Linq [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) function with [`char.IsDigit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58(v=vs.110).aspx):

`return str.All(char.IsDigit);`

Comment: Not quite: `str = "۰۱۲۳۴۵۶"` (*Persian* digits) passes the test when we have `0..9` in the question

Comment: And `str = ""` (empty string) will pass also

Comment: Also there is no lambda expression in this answer which the OP explicitly asked for. I'm not 100% clear on whether the OP wants a pure lambda expression or a linq expression using lambda but an answer without any lamba expression seems to not be what is required...

Comment: @HansKesting Note that `str = ""` will pass even with the OP's code.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed true, it is just something to be aware of: `.All()` returns true on an empty list. That was unexpected for me when it bit me :-)

Comment: @HansKesting, Yep, it's quite annoying actually. The problem is that `.All()` [uses `foreach` internally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,be4bfd025bd2724c), returns `false` if it finds a mismatch inside the loop, and returns true after the end of the loop.

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed  It's not just `.All()` or `.Any()`. Could be `.TakeWhile()`, `Where()` etc.  A test for an empty set is mandatory. In this case could be something like:  `bool result = !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Input) || Input.Any(c => !char.IsNumber(c)));`